# User privacy and code of law in mobile applications

Tags: user-expectation, legal

In many mobile applications you could find privacy section.
For example, you could open iOS application Facebook Messenger and navigate to Account -> Privacy & Terms.

Here you could find list.

- Data Policy
- Terms of Service
- Third-party Notices

Here I suggest you to consider another application Google Hangouts for iOS platform.
Open app and navigate to Settings -> About

Here you could find list.

- Privacy Policy
- Terms of Service
- Licenses

Question is which of these documents should contain app to be legal?

Comment: I don't really understand the question you're asking here. Are you asking which of these things you need to include in an application in order for that application to be legal? That's what it looks like, but legal requirements will vary from one country /  application purpose to another.

Answer (score 1):

There is no proper location for Legal Terms & Conditions.
Some apps keeps it in front at about section so they will be aware of it and company will not be in trouble if something goes wrong.
Some apps keeps it in support section well it depends on what is your product.
Facebook case they land in trouble a lot and their features are messed up and they have a seperate section called datapolicy this is mainly because they have lot of policies and they try to be safe so it's upfront in seperate section.
Hope this helps